# Pycrytpo and mySQL problems

Tags: python, mysql, encryption, pycrypto

Hello I'm trying to store information in a mysql db. I want it to be encryped but I want to be able to get back to the plain text version from time to time. The column I'm currently working with is a varchar btw and I'm using Python3.6 and PyCrypto

To encrypt, I call pycrypto's encrypt function which returns a bytes object. I can't store that in the db, but if I change it to a string I can store it. I could store either estr or encrypted after decode, they're the same. This is what encrypted looks like before conversion to a string:

b'\x8ae"\xd5\xdd:s!*\x1b\x11!7\x16\xbel'

```
encrypted = encryption_suite.encrypt(plainText)
estr = ''.join(chr(x) for x in encrypted)
encrypted = encrypted.decode("unicode_escape")
```

When I retrieve the encrypted string and try to decode it, I'm unable to get back to the original text. I get the following error "Input strings must be a multiple of 16 in length". Here's that code:

```
db_val = get string from db 
bytes_ = db_val.encode('unicode_escape')
decrypted = decryption_suite.decrypt(bytes_)#this line results in the above error
```

b'?e"\xd5\xdd:s!*\x1b\x11!7\x16\xbel'
  is what bytes_ looks like. Which is pretty similar to the value of the original encrypted string but the beginning is off.

Any ideas on how to go about resolving this?

Answer (score 0):

**Don't** try and convert arbitrary binary data to a Unicode string.  It simply doesn't work that way.  It's like converting arbitrary binary data to a MP3 file and then complaining that it won't play.

**Do** convert your arbitrary binary data to a base64 or hex-encoded string.  These encodings were designed to do exactly what you're attempting now.

Comment: Thanks. This pointed me in the right direction. Will update with sample code.